# How to make 'cd' command work from my own custom shell?

Tags: c, linux, shell, system-calls

I'm currently doing my Homework for UNIX(LINUX) programming.
I was assigned to build my own custom shell that all commonly used linux command and custom program can work.

I also created `my_ls`, `my_cp`, `my_rm`, `my_cd` for checking that both linux command and my own command works.

Simple story's are below

```sh
./myOwnShell         // Run my own shell
home/testFolder>>ls .    // Shell prompt
a.out helloWorld.txt myOwnShell.c myOwnShell // Print ls command's result
home/test/Folder>>my_ls . // Run my own ls command program
a.out helloWorld.txt myOwnShell.c myOwnShell
```

So far, all the linux command (which in /bin/) and my own command (which in home//bin/) works.
But it comes with differences when I type `cd` and `my_cd` - which changes current cwd

```
home/testFolder>>cd ..
Fail to run program // Error message from exec function failure
home/testFolder>>my_cd ..
// No message but also cwd is not changed
home/testFolder>>   // Prompt from same folder
```

Somewhat pseudo source codes are below for myShell program
(I cannot copy/paste for my source cause it is in university server and transfer protocols are blocked)

```
int main() {
   char** res; // store command by tokening
   while (1) {
     printf("%s>>", cwd);
     gets(in); // get command
     // <Some codes that split `in` by space and store it into res>
     // <If cmd is "ls ./folder" -> res = ["ls", "./folder", NULL]>
      
      pid = fork();
      if (pid == 0) { // child
        if (execvp(res[0], res) == -1) { // Run 'ls' command
          printf("Fail to run program");
          exit(0); // Exit child process
        }
      } else { // Parent, I omit in case of fork failure
         wait(0);
         // Omit exit status checking code
      }
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Command `cd` is linux built-in command,
Command `my_cd` is my own program which change it's cwd.

And I do know that changing child process's cwd cannot effect to parent process and that's why 'cd' dose not change my shell's cwd. And I found that `cd` command is not in `/bin/`, so I guess `cd`is coded inside linux shell.

How can I make it work?

1. For linux `cd`
2. For my own `my_cd` -- I don't have it's source code, only have program. It is from my professor.

My guess is that `cd` cannot be implemented unless it is coded in shell itself. But professor give me this homework and it can mean that it is possible.

Any idea please?

Comment: Study the source code of some existing open source shell such as [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [zsh](http://zsh.org/) or [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) and see [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).  Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Comment: The `cd` command is a special builtin — it does not execute an external binary (even though one of `/bin/cd` or `/usr/bin/cd` will exist on POSIX systems).

Comment: If you are truly writing you own *shell* then the current directory is merely an internal state of it. So your `cd` will simply change it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I skimmed docs you give me and first, really appreciate. Seems it can be the answer. But problem is this is academic course and we didn't learn about further advanced stuffs. Maybe I can implement with your helps. But is there any other way? Need something extremely simple way for content professor. Seems very stupid idea. We just learned list of common syscall excluding it's internal works.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I thought so, Problem is why professor gave such Homework? I think there are some ways with simple ways.

Comment: I take it back — `cd` is not a special builtin per POSIX — [Shell — Special Built-ins](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14); it is just a utility ([`cd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html)).  However, it is normally actually a built-in — because it must affect the current process's current directory, and an executed command cannot do that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can this mean that cd is program which reside in /bin? I cannot find 'cd' program inside /bin.

Comment: It depends on your system.  On Linux, I can do `ls -l /usr/bin/cd` and get information such as `-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 26 Sep 26  2017 /usr/bin/cd`.  Similarly on macOS.  However, the shells do _not_ execute those binaries when you type `cd` at your shell prompt, or when there is a `cd` command in a shell script.  It uses a built-in command `cd` which executes the `chdir()` system call.

Comment: `sash` is a simple shell, of less than seven thousand lines of C code. Download http://members.tip.net.au/%7Edbell/programs/sash-3.8.tar.gz and read the C code after extracting it with `tar xvf sash-3.8.tar.gz`. You should read that C code in a few hours

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: on my Debian/Sid I don't have any `/usr/bin/cd`. Which package is it from? (yes, I know POSIX requires it)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch — not sure; I am reporting from RHEL 7.4 (and macOS 10.14.6).

Comment: Do you have the URL of the source code of `/usr/bin/cd` ? For me it is mythical! Or is it a shell script? (we both know that it won't really work)

Comment: The output from `cat /usr/bin/cd` on the RHEL box is:
`#!/bin/sh` —
`builtin cd "$@"` (two lines — you might notice the file size in the `ls` listing is only 26 bytes; that's what those 26 bytes are).  The external executable `cd` internally changes directory, and reports success or failure, but doesn't (cannot) affect the current working directory of the process that forks and executes `/usr/bin/cd`.

Comment: See also the [Shell commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09) section of the POSIX specification — especially the "Command Search and Execution" sub-subsection of the [Simple Commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) subsection.

Comment: The [Posix rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap01.html#tag_23_01_07) is also relevant, or at least interesting.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I downloaded sash codes and look for cd command and I found that cd dose not fork any process or execute any other process. And there are function for cd which use chdir() sys call. It means that chdir is executed inside the shell program not forking any other process what do 'cd' things. And seems this means that implementing cd as program is not make sense. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right.*